# Not found: The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again

Tags: python-3.x, flask, deep-learning, pytorch

I have written a small deep learning method to practice deplyoing with a Flask application. It's a simple application that just needs to distinguish a cat from a fish.

Here is the short code:

```
from io import BytesIO
import requests
import torch
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from PIL import Image
from torchvision import transforms
from catfish_model import  catfish_classes, catfish_model

def load_model():
    m = catfish_model
    m.eval()
    return m

load_model()

img_transforms = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize((224, 224)), 
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                             std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    ])

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route("/")
    def status():
        return jsonify({"status": "ok"})


    @app.route("/predict", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def predict():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            img_url = request.form.image_url
        else:
            img_url = request.args.get('image_url', '')

        response = requests.get(img_url)
        img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
        img_tensor = img_transforms(img).unsqueeze(0)
        prediction =  model(img_tensor)
        predicted_class = CatfishClasses[torch.argmax(prediction)]
        return jsonify({"image": img_url, "prediction": predicted_class})



    return app

def main():
    app = create_app()
    app.run(debug=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is how I launch the Flask app:

```
set FLASK_APP=catfish_server.py
flask run --port=8080
```

Then i am starting the browser an give the follow command to predict if the pic on an webside is a cat or a fish:

```
127.0.0.1:8080/predict image_url=https://www.augsburger-allgemeine.de/img/bilder/crop55113376/4006562429-cv16_9-w1880/Bailey-aus-Gundelfingen.jpg
```

now I get the error message:

> The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

I don't understand exactly why.

Comment: When I am starting with: python catfish_server.py then it works when I start in the browser with : `127.0.0.1:5000/predict?image_url=https://www.augsburger-allgemeine.de/img/bilder/crop55113376/4006562429-cv16_9-w1880/Bailey-aus-Gundelfingen.jpg`. It's running on Windows 11 ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a space in the URL makes sense. I think you should put a ?.

```
127.0.0.1:8080/predict?image_url=https://www.augsburger-allgemeine.de/img/bilder/crop55113376/4006562429-cv16_9-w1880/Bailey-aus-Gundelfingen.jpg
```

However in flask you can do this:

```
@app.route("/predict/<img_url>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def predict(img_url):
    img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
    img_tensor = img_transforms(img).unsqueeze(0)
    prediction =  model(img_tensor)
    predicted_class = CatfishClasses[torch.argmax(prediction)]
    return jsonify({"image": img_url, "prediction": predicted_class})
```

Comment: When I am starting with: python catfish_server.py then it works when I start in the browser with : 127.0.0.1:5000/predict?image_url=https://www.augsburger-allgemeine.de/img/bilder/crop55113376/4006562429-cv16_9-w1880/Bailey-aus-Gundelfingen.jpg. It's running on Windows 11 ;-)

Comment: Yes, exactly, in your question you had a space in place of the ?

Comment: Thanks for your help ;-) But with the commands `set FLASK_APP=catfish_server.py` and `flask run` it doesn't work :-(